# vscode cannot open shell in integrated terminal on macos

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I try to open the integrated terminal on my vscode, I get an empty one where I cannot type anything and it never loads.
[image]

Sometimes, when I just rebooted for example, I am able to open one correctly with my shell but I can't figure out why. I installed vscode with nix and my config used to work perfectly on my mac mini. When I open a normal terminal outside of vscode I do not have this issue.

```json
  "terminal": {
    "integrated": {
      "shell": {
        "linux": "/nix/store/by2x6dh0sls8aqhi71jnas2y4gmdcyxa-zsh-5.9/bin/zsh",
        "osx": "/nix/store/by2x6dh0sls8aqhi71jnas2y4gmdcyxa-zsh-5.9/bin/zsh"
      }
    }
  },
```

The paths are correct, when I type them in a working terminal I get zsh.